# PDO вывод в цикле данных всех пользователей

Tags: pdo, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица с данными пользователей, в ней есть поля login и mail.

Нужно вывести данные ВСЕХ пользователей из этих полей.

Извлекаю данные так:

```
 if  ($result = $db->prepare("SELECT `login`, `mail` FROM `users` "))

  {

        $result->execute();
        $res = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY);
    }
```

Так вот, собсна, вопрос, как теперь мне циклом вывести все данные по типу:

```
echo '<p class = "login">' $login '</p><p class = "mail">' $mail '</p>';
```

Повторюсь - именно циклом нужно. Либо мб у PDO есть функция, которая позволит использовать послежовательно все записи из таблицы?

Comment: PDO::FETCH_ARRAY что то новенькое ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT `login`, `mail` FROM `users` ");
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while($res = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
        echo '<p class = "login">', $res['login'] , '</p>
              <p class = "mail">', $res['mail'] , '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Пока писал уже ответили. Добавлю, что есть функия fetchAll если хочется работать с результатом как с массивом а не как с итератором/ Ну и проверку количества строк можно не делать. Если ноль просто вернется false и ничего не произойдет

Comment: @donkey, во-первых,  FETCH_BOTH  или FETCH_ASSOC - дело лично ТС, кому-то и FETCH_OBJ ближе к телу. fetchAll() - кушает больше памяти, не советую. Проверять количество строк или как булевый результат - не принципиально.

Comment: @Deonis В оригинале было вообще FETCH_ARRAY написано

Comment: @Deonis ибо спутал,с пдо недавно работаю, так что еще запарки в некоторых местах бывают